# Primefaces - CommandButton toggled based on bean value without CSS

Tags: java, primefaces, toggle

I'd like to have a commandbutton to be toggled if a boolean var in the bean is true and vice-versa. I'm not talking about it being enabled or disabled, I'd like it to look like it's pressed. Is it possible to do it without CSS?

I tried button, commandbutton, button, booleanbutton and even rating but non of those suited me.

How could I do it?

Comment: Inspect the button with a developer tool and check which classes differ when pressed. Add them any way you like... Yes it is css but it's the only way possible (without actua;ly clicking it) One question: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces has a "selectBooleanButton" which is linked to a boolean in your bean. In the Primefaces showcase, if you click the button, it is highlighted.  I would think that if the backend boolean value is true to begin with, the button would default to a selected state.  You can even specify the button text to display if the button is selected or not.

Comment: I tried the selectBooleanButton but I probably overlooked it and got rid of it pretty fast.
Thank you for making me give it another try, it looks like it's extactly what I need!